# Problem transforming a variable in logs, python

Tags: python

I am using Python. I would like to create a new column which is the log transformation of column 'lights1992'.

I am using the following code:

```
log_lights1992 = np.log(lights1992)
```

I obtain the following error:

[image]

I have tried two things: 1) adding a 1 to each value and transform the column 'lights1992' to numeric.

```
city_join['lights1992'] = pd.to_numeric(city_join['lights1992'])
city_join["lights1992"] = city_join["lights1992"] + 1
```

However, that two solution has not worked. Variable 'lights1992' is a float64 type. Do you know what can be the problem?

Edit:

The variable 'lights1992' comes from doing a zonal_statistics from a raster 'junk1992', maybe this affect.

```
zs1 = zonal_stats(city_join, junk1992, stats=['mean'], nodata=np.nan)  
city_join['lights1992'] = [x['mean'] for x in zs1]
```

Comment: Code and traceback **don't match** (*numpy* *vs* *np*). You probably assigned something to a variable named *np* (and thus shadowing the module).

Comment: It's np but I putted numpy to make things clearer. Sorry, I have fixed. I do "import numpy as np". Do you know what can be going on @CristiFati ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the traceback states:

```
'DatasetReader' object has no attribute'log'.
```

Did you re-assign numpy to something else at some point? I can't find much about 'DatasetReader' is that a custom class?

EDIT:

I think you would need to pass the whole column because your edit doesn't show a variable named 'lights1992'

so instead of:

```
np.log(lights1992)
```

can you try passing in the Dataframe's column to log?:

```
np.log(city_join['lights1992'])
```

2ND EDIT:

Since you've reported back that it works I'll dive into the why a little bit.

In your original statement you called the log function and gave it an argument, then you assigned the result to a variable name:

```
log_lights1992 = np.log(lights1992)
```

The problem here is that when you give python text without any quotes it thinks you are giving it a variable name (see how you have log_lights1992 on the left of the equal sign? You wanted to assign the results of the operation on the right hand side of the equal sign to the variable name log_lights1992) but in this case I don't think lights1992 had any value!

So there were two ways to make it work, either what I said earlier:

1. Instead of giving it a variable name you give .log the column of the city_join dataframe (that's what city_join["lights1992"]) directly.

Or

2. You assign the value of that column to the variable name **first** then you pass it in to .log, like this:

   lights1992 = city_join["lights1992"]
   log_lights1992 = np.log(lights1992)

Hope that clears it up for you!

Comment: I do "import numpy as np" and I do not touch that at all after.

Comment: What is a custom class? I am a bit new in Python. Thank you for your answer @hassium

Comment: So when you wrote np.log(your_variable), the error said that DatasetReader has no attribute .log. Meaning that in your case "np" has evaluated to the object DatasetReader.

I can't find anything about an object called DatasetReader in the source code for Numpy so I thought maybe you had created it but it doesn't sound like it...

Could you update your question with your code that would some extra info of how you got to this line? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @hassium . I have editted my question saying from where my variable 'lights1992' comes.

Comment: I edited my answer, let me know if that works for you.

Comment: It really works now! Thank you so much, @hassium ! Could you explain why works now? I would also like to understand the problem, not just knowing the solution. Thank you again!

Comment: No problem, I edited my answer again with the explanation of the what and why. I just wanted to be sure it worked for your problem before expanding too much, just in case it was unrelated. Glad I could be of help.